# How To Get Image With Correct Direction From Asset

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to rotate image with correction direction

I have placed below code , But not Working

```
UIImage *images  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullScreenImage] scale:[rep scale] orientation:0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImageOrientation` specifies the possible orientations of an image:

```
typedef enum {
   UIImageOrientationUp,
   UIImageOrientationDown ,   // 180 deg rotation 
   UIImageOrientationLeft ,   // 90 deg CW 
   UIImageOrientationRight ,   // 90 deg CCW 
   UIImageOrientationUpMirrored ,    // as above but image mirrored along 
       // other axis. horizontal flip 
   UIImageOrientationDownMirrored ,  // horizontal flip 
   UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored ,  // vertical flip 
   UIImageOrientationRightMirrored , // vertical flip 
} UIImageOrientation;
```

In your code you are passing `0`, which means `UIImageOrientationUp` enum value, for you it looks like default image of course.
So you need to specify this parameter to what kind of orientation you want.

E.g. following code will do vertical image flip:

```
UIImage *images = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullScreenImage] scale:[rep scale] orientation: UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];
```